# Div overwrites another div content

Tags: css, html

I tried with setting the `z-index` values in `div` but it does not make any change.
see:

[image]

As we can see the `preview content` is overwridden by buttons which are in `div` tag. 
The `z-index` value in the `div` which has those button is `1`. I tried with making it `2,3` and `-1` for the div which shows preview. But no change?

Does it need any other change?

Here is my html code:

```
<body style="height: 560px">
    <div >
    <form action="data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
            <div style="z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 40px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">           
               <label>Enter URL:</label><br/>
            </div>

    <div style=" width: 15%;margin: auto;margin-top: 1px;text-decoration: none;text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;    padding: 10px 20px;    text-align: justify; ">

   <!-- This div linkpreview shows div preview -->

    <div class="linkPreview" style="z-index: 2;"> 

                <div id="previewLoading"></div>
                <div style="float: left;">
                    <textarea type="text" id="text" style="text-align: left; height:35px; width:512px; " placeholder="What's in your mind"/>
                    </textarea>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="preview" style="z-index: -1;">
                    <div id="previewImages">
                        <div id="previewImage"><img src="img/loader.gif" style="margin-left: 43%; margin-top: 39%;" ></img>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="photoNumber" value="0" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="previewContent">
                        <div id="closePreview" title="Remove" ></div>
                        <div id="previewTitle"></div>
                        <div id="previewUrl"></div>
                        <div id="previewDescription"></div>
                        <div id="hiddenDescription"></div>
                        <div id="previewButtons" >
                            <div id="previewPreviousImg" class="buttonLeftDeactive" ></div><div id="previewNextImg" class="buttonRightDeactive"  ></div>
                            <div class="photoNumbers" ></div>
                            <div class="chooseThumbnail">
                                Choose a thumbnail
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="noThumb" class="noThumbCb" />
                        <div class="nT"  >
                            <span id="noThumbDiv" >No thumbnail</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
                <div id="postPreview">
                </div>
                <div class="previewPostedList"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
       <div style="z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 110px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px" onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('t1').value)" >  <button onclick="show2();"> Get Sentiment </button>       
            </div>
         </form>
         <div style="z-index: 1; left: 720px; top: 110px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px"> 
            <button onclick="makeAjaxCall(); return false;" value="View Graph" >   View Graph   </button>
         </div>
         </div>
        <h4>

      </body>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or provide code that would enable to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Im confused... How exactly do you want those two buttons to be showing up? Below the `preview content` or underneath them?

Comment: Additionally, how you want that to happen? To move the buttons down, or just have the preview appear on top of those buttons?

Comment: @Kierchon: I want preview part should be shown on top completely

Comment: Okay where should the buttons go then?

Comment: If you want them to go below you need to get rid of your absolute positioning on them. Or make your `top:300px` or something greater than 110

Comment: @Kierchon: preview appear for few second only. When user click on close button it will disappear. So when user enters url in the box at that instance only I want preview to be appear on top of those buttons. Buttons need not to be repositioned

Comment: Then you will need to provide some working code so we can chew on... Guessing game is hard for you and us

Answer (score 0):

Try making it 1000. It should work then.

Comment: I am not in mood of jocking!

Comment: I was serious :( .. I mean it.. Can you please try it once

Comment: tough to guess without something to fiddle with, but you have the 2 buttons in a absolute position. Do you want the buttons to go underneath the text or what?

Comment: then you have a positioning issue. You have the buttons at top:110px; which means they are position:absolute from the top at 110px. You need to make them more than that to put them under the preview, like 200px;

Comment: @Keith: I am not worried about buttons. If they get hidden by preview no issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a positioning issue. You have the buttons at top:110px; which means they are position:absolute from the top at 110px. You need to make them more than that to put them under the preview, like 200px;

Comment: In that case buttons will move down. I dont want to reposition them,
preview appear for few second only. When user click on close button it will disappear. So when user enters url in the box at that instance only I want preview to be appear on top of those buttons. Buttons need not to be repositioned

Comment: You can write a simple javascript and have them fade in or do a hide/show css

Answer (score 0):

You should be more descriptive in your original question but from what I've picked up from your comments you want to hide and show them based off the preview. To do this in your sylying make them hidden.

```
    <div id="BTN1" style="display:none; z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 110px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px" onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('t1').value)" > 
        <button onclick="show2();"> Get Sentiment </button>       
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="BTN2" style="display:none; z-index: 1; left: 720px; top: 110px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px"> 
        <button onclick="makeAjaxCall(); return false;" value="View Graph" >   View Graph   </button>
     </div>
```

Then when you press the close button to the preview you can make `BTN1` and `BTN2` show again. If you tell me what html element is in charge of closing the preview and will show the two buttons I can help you write the code for making them show again

EDIT: I think I found it.

`<div id="closePreview" title="Remove" ></div>`

Im assuming on this line you have a function that closes the preview. In there just show BTN1 and BTN2

Comment: Okay let me know. I'm assuming you know how to show the div again